# How do I get to know my optical drives read and write capabilities?

Tags: linux, dvd, data-cd, blu-ray

I want to learn which media my optical device can read and write to?

Comment: It appears this Q is Linux-based, based on the accepted Answer.

Comment: um, yes, unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Versus Solaris or HP-UX or AIX, all of which would have different commands for this.

Comment: Oh well, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lshw!

> lshw
>
> lshw -class disk